# Updating UITextView value from shouldChangeTextIn returns character twice

Tags: swift, uitextview, hashtag

I want to implement HasTag in `UITextView` while user typing text in `UITextView`.

For that i have tried below code.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        self.txtB.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    let numberOfChars = newText.count

    self.txtB.attributedText = CommonHelper.sharedInstance.convert(self.txtB.text.findMentionText(), string: self.txtB.text)
    return numberOfChars < 121 //120 limit
}
```

## HasTag functions

```
func findMentionText() -> [String] {
    var arr_hasStrings:[String] = []
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(#[a-zA-Z0-9_\\p{Arabic}\\p{N}]*)", options: [])
    if let matches = regex?.matches(in: self, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
        for match in matches {
            arr_hasStrings.append(NSString(string: self).substring(with: NSRange(location:match.range.location, length: match.range.length )))
        }
    }
    return arr_hasStrings
}


func convert(_ hashElements:[String], string: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let hasAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.init(name: Fonts.PoppinsBoldItalic, size: 16.0)]
    let normalAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.init(name: Fonts.PoppinsBoldItalic, size: 16.0)]

    let mainAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: normalAttribute)
    let txtViewReviewText = string as NSString

    hashElements.forEach { if string.contains($0) {
        mainAttributedString.addAttributes(hasAttribute, range: txtViewReviewText.range(of: $0))
        }
    }
    return mainAttributedString
}
```

If i type single character then textview have that character twice.

how to fix this?

Comment: Is self.txtBeep is the same textView?

Comment: @PGDev, yes self.txtB is my textView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the below lines,

```
self.txtBeep.attributedText = CommonHelper.sharedInstance.convert(self.txtB.text.findMentionText(), string: self.txtB.text)

return numberOfChars < 121 //120 limit
```

1. In **line-1**, you're setting the `text` in `textView` as per your requirement.
2. In **line-2**, if `numberOfChars < 121`, `true` will be `returned`, which means `append the text to the textView`.

This is the reason the `text` is entered twice in the `textView` in case `numberOfChars < 121`.

**Solution:**

The `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` method must be like,

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        self.txtB.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    let numberOfChars = newText.count
    if numberOfChars > 120 {
        return false
    }

    self.txtB.attributedText = CommonHelper.sharedInstance.convert(newText.findMentionText(), string: newText)
    return false
}
```

Comment: how can i fix my issue and keep 120 character limit as well as hastag?

Comment: If i write above line that typed character isn't typing 2nd time. like if i type A and then again try to type A then it doesn't type.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Now i'm able to type duplicate character but the hastag value textcolor is not proper. (If i type **#virat** then Orange color is only applied to **#vira** not applied to **t**)

Comment: Right. Pass `newText` while calling `convert` method. See the answer.

Comment: `convert(newText.findMentionText(), string: newText)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help to fix my issue.

Comment: I have another question related to this. will you please guid me about my new question.

Comment: Yes sure. Let me know the issue.

Comment: This is broken since ios 16